# How do not cache a dynamic routes

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I try to add my dynamic route like a service. 
routes.yml:

```
static_pages:
    resource: 'pages.dynamic_routing_provider:getRoutes'
    type: service
```

Service.php

```
class DynamicRoutingProvider {
    public function getRoutes(): RouteCollection
    {
        $builder = new RouteCollectionBuilder();

        $options = [
            'cache_dir' => null,
            'generator_cache_class' => null
        ];

        $route = new Route('dynamic-pages', ['_controller' => 'PagesBundle:Pages:preview'], [], $options);
        $builder->addRoute($route);

        return $builder->build();
    }
}
```

How to make my dynamic route not fall into this file:

```
 /cache/appProductionDebugSilexProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php
 /cache/appProductionDebugSilexProjectContainerUrlGenerator.php
```

Example:

1. I have a route localhost/dynamic-pages/page1
   Then in the admin panel, I rename my route for page2
2. I have a route localhost/dynamic-pages/page1
   Then in the admin panel, I remove this route.

In the final, I have a problem because this route exists in the cache folder.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand the problem. Are you saying that the cached route already exists and your new provider or changes you make in your provider are not registered? Can you please elaborate what the caching problem is? Are you caching the routes or is the default caching of compiled routes by Symfony the issue?

Comment: I don't want the framework to cache my dynamic route.
I don't want to see my dynamic route in the cache folder.
How torn off cache for my route?